# How can I write a valid JSON format when I want to pass variables in it?

Tags: apex, json

Following is the valid JSON format:

```
String json = '{'+
        '        \"A\": \"Value of A\",'+
        '        \"B\": \"Value of B\",'+
        '        \"C\": \"Value of C\"        '+
        '}';
```

How should I build JSON?

If I wanted to save value of A, B and C in a variable and parse that.

```
String str1 = 'Value of A';
String str2 = 'Value of B';
String str3 = 'Value of C';
```

I tried the following:

```
String json = '{'+
        '        \"A\": \"'+str1+'\",'+
        '        \"B\": \"'+str2+'\",'+
        '        \"C\": \"'+str3+'\"        '+
        '}';
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You should not be escaping the double quotes inside the string, but escape only single quotes:

```
String jsonString = '{"A":"Some Value for A", "B", "B\'s Value"}';
```

Or alternatively you can build a map and then serialize it:

```
Map <String, String> jsonMap = new Map <String, String> ();
jsonMap.put('A', 'Some Value for A');
jsonMap.put('B', 'Some Value for B');
jsonMap.put('C', 'Some Value for C');
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(jsonMap);
```

Comment: This answer actually illustrates exactly why developers should be using JSON.serialize-- your first line has a typo (a comma where a colon should be). Libraries are meant to make life easier, and we should use them when we can.

Answer (score 3):

After little more research into understanding Salesforce inbuilt JSON libraries, I ended up using JSONGenerator's

```
JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);  
generator.writeStartObject();      
generator.writeStringField('A', 'Value of A');   
generator.writeStringField('B', 'Value of B');   
generator.writeStringField('C', 'Value of C');  

generator.writeEndObject();    

String jsonString = generator.getAsString();
system.debug('----------------------------------------------'+jsonString);
```

Hope this is efficient way I guess. I also like the idea of build the hasp map with objects and serializing it.

Thanks so much Bachovski for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the static String.format() method?

It doesn't seem to like the `{` and `}`  characters, but if it is just a simple JSON object you could do this:

```
List<String> values = new List<String>{'red','green','blue'};
String str = '"A":"{0}","B":"{1}","C":"{2}"';

String jsonString = '{' + String.format(str,values) + '}';
```